# -Define a predicate to display all multiples of

Tags: logic

i have ERROR in this code in prolog can you help me?

```
div(X):- X mod 3 =:= 0.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
div(X):- X mod 3 =:= 0 ...
div(X):- X mod 3 =:=1  ...
```

`2 mod 3` is not 0 or 1, so there is no way to do `div(2)`, so it fails.

Maybe you wanted

```
X mod 3 =:= 0    % remainder 0
X mod 3 =\= 0    % remainder not 0
```

?